# User control events not getting to their handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I am trying to create a user control to wrap around the Membership API (A set of custom Gridviews to display the data better) and, while the code and the controls worked fine in the page, when I moved them to an .ascx, the events stopped firing to it.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomMembership.ascx.cs" Inherits="CCGlink.CustomMembership" %>
<asp:Panel ID="mainPnl" runat="server">
<asp:Label 
    id="lblError"
    ForeColor="Red" 
    Font-Bold="true"
    runat="server" />
<asp:GridView
    id="grdUsers"
    HeaderStyle-cssclass="<%# _headercss %>"
    RowStyle-cssclass="<%# _rowcss %>"
    AlternatingRowStyle-cssclass="<%# _alternatingcss %>"
    OnRowUpdating="grdUsers_RowUpdating"
    OnRowDeleting="grdUsers_RowDeleting"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="grdUsers_cancelEdit"
    autogeneratecolumns="false"
    allowsorting="true"
    AllowPaging="true"
    EmptyDataText="No users..."
    pagesize="<%# PageSizeForBoth %>"
    runat="server">
<!-- ...columns... -->
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button
    id="btnAllDetails"
    onclick="btnAllDetails_clicked"
    text="Full Info"
    runat="server" />
<asp:GridView 
    DataKeyNames="UserName"
    HeaderStyle-cssclass="<%# _headercss %>"
    RowStyle-cssclass="<%# _rowcss %>"
    AlternatingRowStyle-cssclass="<%# _alternatingcss %>"
    id="grdAllDetails"
    visible="false"
    allowsorting="true"
    EmptyDataText="No users in DB."
    pagesize="<%# PageSizeForBoth %>"
    runat="server" />
<asp:Button
    id="btnDoneAllDetails"
    onclick="btnAllDetails_clicked"
    text="Done."
    Visible="false"
    runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

However, none of the events in the first two controls (the gridview grdUsers and the button btnAllDetails) simply do NOT occur, I have verified this in the debugger. If they occured just fine in the aspx page, why do they die on moving to the ascx?

My code in the aspx now is:

```
 <div class="admin-right">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server" />
    <h1>User Management</h1>
    <div class="admin-right-users">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cm1:CustomMembership
            id="showUsers" 
            PageSizeForBoth="9" 
            AlternatingRowStylecssclass="alternating"
            RowStylecssclass="row"
            DataSource="srcUsers"
            HeaderStylecssclass="header" 
            runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: comment sorry for the misformatted aspx... StackOverflow mangled my divs before.

Comment: I've tracked it down somewhat. It seems that my page is, for whatever reason, calling Page_Load twice, once as a postback, one is not!!
Any idea why the system would throw two postbacks to a single user control?

Answer (score 0):

You've not said whether you're building a Web Site or a Web Application - if you're building a web application have you checked that the .designer file has updated properly when you moved the controls into the user control?

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1102183.aspx

This explains that there is an issue with ButtonType="Image" in the CommandField. Changing the entry to "Link" fixes this problem.